# Is it possible to use inner functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I get access to my `y()` function?

```
function x() {
    function y() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is scoped to `x`, kind of like:

```
function x() {
    var y;
}
```

So, yes, from within `x`, and no otherwise.

If you wanted it to be, you could create it as a property on `x`:

```
var x = (function () {
    function x() {
        …
    }

    function y() {
        …
    }

    x.y = y;

    return x;
})();
```

Comment: Ok. Here is another question, can I invoke y() from outside x()?

Comment: @user3633595: > So, yes, from within `x`, and **no otherwise**.

Answer (score 0):

You mean access it from outside the function `x`?

That's not possible, the function `y` doesn't exist when `x` is not running. It's declared locally inside `x` so it's only accessible inside `x`.

To make it accessible outside `x` you need to expose a reference to it outside the function. If you expose a reference to it, it survives after the function ends. For example:

```
function x() {
  function y() {
    return 1;
  }
  return y;
}

// get the reference to y
var f = x();
// call y
f();
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution. But I want to store `y()` like independent function without `return y;` in `x()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to your **y** function inside of the scope of the **x** function Only.
But you can get access to the **y** function if you return it from your **x** function or assign it to a global variable or to the variable that is in scope outside of your **x** function. This is also know is **closure**, your **y** function will keep the reference in memory to the scope it was created in if you pass it around.

```
function x() {
    var anotherNum= 2;
    function y() {
        return 1 + anotherNum;
    }

    return y;
}
```

Now you can get the **y** function along with the scope it was created in. Notice that it will use anotherNum in the computation as it was created in the **x** function.

```
var yFunc = x();
console.log(yFunc()) // will print 3
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to return it out of the scope

```
function x() {
    function y() {
        return 1;
    }
    return { 
        y:y         
    };
}
```

Whenever you call x(), it returns an object with the function y as a member

```
var a = x();
a.y();  //this returns 1
```

This is similar to the revealing module pattern described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FClosures

Also good to read up on closures:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FClosures